# Kivy : how to selected date from calendar put in TextBox?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

How to use `DatePicker` based on `TextInput`?When `textinput` field focused shows popup with `CalendarWidget`.Once data selected then selected date don't put into `textinput` field.

## demo.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from KivyCalendar import CalendarWidget
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (400, 250)

class SetIndex(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SetIndex, self).__init__()

    def setDate(self):
        self.cal = CalendarWidget(as_popup=True)
        self.popup = Popup(title='Calendar', content=self.cal, size_hint=(1, 1))
        self.popup.open()


class Demo(App):
    def build(self):
        return SetIndex()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Demo().run()
```

## demo.kv

```
<SetIndex>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20
        size_hint_y: .5

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint_x: .6

            Label:
                text: "TEXT"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: .2

            TextInput:
                size_hint_x: .4
                id: old_date
                on_focus: root.setDate()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which python version do you use?
KivyCalendar is a dated library written with 2.7 python version in mind, it does not work with 3.6 python at all.
Unless you are willing to use an unsupported, dated library, I would advice you to find an alternative.

UPD:
Okay, so I could not find any alternatives, here is how this library work:
You need to setup a DatePicker which is a textinput with all the necessary popup/value handling

```
<SetIndex>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20
        size_hint_y: .5

        DatePicker:
            pHint: 1,1
            size_hint_x: .4
            id: old_date
```

You actual code only needs to import DatePicker, that is all there is to it

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from KivyCalendar import DatePicker
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (400, 250)

class SetIndex(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SetIndex, self).__init__()

class Demo(App):
    def build(self):
        return SetIndex()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Demo().run()
```

Comment: thanks. i am using 2.7 python.Please can you refer me alternative link of datepicker?I am new to python/kivy.I can not find.

Comment: I've updated the answer, for any other popular Kivy user created widgets, there is the https://github.com/kivy-garden Graden project. Hope this helps.